# The action 'update' could not be found for InfosController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, controller, action

So I have a site that I'm trying to make, in which you can enter a title and a price for a object called Info. When I enter in the title and price and press submit, the page that it gets redirected to says "The action 'update' could not be found for InfosController". I want it to flash a message notifying the user that the object was created successfully. Any Help??

controllers/infos_controller.rb

```
class InfosController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @info = Info.new
  end

def create
    @info = Info.new(params[:info])

if @info.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Object created successfully, thank you'
    render :index
   else
    flash[:notice] = 'Sorry! Object was not created successfully'
    render :new
  end
end
  def update
    @info = Info.find(params[:id])
    if @info.update_attributes(params[:info])
        # if update is successful
    else 
        # if update is unsuccessful
    end
    redirect_to infos_path
end
end
```

views/infos/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Please enter information about an Info object</h1>
<%= form_for @info, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
<%= f.label :title %><br />
<%= f.text_field :title %> <br />
<%= f.label :price %><br />
<%= f.text_field :price %> <br />
<%= f.submit "Submit" %> <br />
<% end %>
```

models/info.rb

```
class Info < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :title
end
```

New error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InfosController#update


Couldn't find Info with id=create


Rails.root: C:/Sites/2/information

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace


app/controllers/infos_controller.rb:18:in `update'


Request


Parameters:


{"utf8"=>"✓",

 "_method"=>"put",

 "authenticity_token"=>"aXaLYDb5yhl2NXNriOf9gub2JcArrkUOdBogX4kcfKA=",

 "info"=>{"title"=>"strawberries",

 "price"=>".89"},

 "commit"=>"Submit",

"id"=>"create"}
```

also, here is views\infos\create.html.erb

```
<h1>Infos#create</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/infos/create.html.erb</p>
<h2><% if flash[:notice] %> <%= flash[:notice] %></h2>
```

Comment: What have you specified in your routes ?

Comment: If you're new to rails you should generate a scaffold to see how all these things work together...  e.g. `rails generate scaffold TestInfo price:decimal title:string`...  Also check out the Ruby Guides, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: Information::Application.routes.draw do
  get "infos/index"

  get "infos/create"
 
  resources :infos

Comment: Thanks Helios, I know how scaffolds work and such, the purpose of this is to get practice to be able to do it without them however. This is for a class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've posted your `InfosController` in its entirety, you're missing the `update` action. Add it akin to as follows:

```
# app/controllers/infos_controller.rb
def update
    @info = Info.find(params[:id])
    if @info.update_attributes(params[:info])
        # if update is successful
    else 
        # if update is unsuccessful
    end
    redirect_to infos_path
end
```

**UPDATE**:

The likely reason why you're not hitting the `create` action is because your form  is submitting to a path that matches the `update` path, rather than the `create` path.

First, if you have implemented RESTful routes for your `infos` resource (as you indicated you have), you shouldn't need to explicitly declare `get "infos/create"` as you have – the create route is implicitly created in your resourceful route declaration.

Then, if you indeed want a `form_for` helper to POST to your `create` action, try passing a hash to the `url` key in your `form_for` declaration:

```
<%= form_for @info, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
```

**UPDATE 2**:

The reason you are not hitting your `update` action is that the path you're posting your form to is `/infos/create`, when [according to the canonical Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions), you *should* be posting to `/infos`. You can resolve this simply be removing the `url` argument in your `form_for` declaration:

```
<%= form_for @info do |f| %>
```

By default, Rails knows to route a `form_for` submission for a new object to the corresponding `create` action of the controller.

The reason why you're hitting the `update` action is that Rails takes the path you're currently submitting to, e.g. `/infos/create`, and routes to the `update` action with a `params[:id]` of `create` (rather than a numerical id). To properly invoke the `update` action, you should pass an *existing* `Info` object (for instance, `Info.first`) to your `form_for` helper. This will automatically route your submission to the `update` action:

```
# app/controllers/infos_controller.rb
def edit
    @info = Info.find(params[:id]) # let's assume the id == 42
end

# app/views/infos/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @info do |f| %>
```

Because you're passing an existing `Info` object, this `form_for` helper will *automatically* POST the request to the path `/infos/42`. Because the HTTP request method is POST, the request will automatically be routed to the `update` action, where `params[:id]` will equal `42` in the example above.

`get "infos/create"` should be dropped from `routes.rb` entirely, since the `create` route is already implicitly created in your `resources :infos` declaration.

Comment: I tried that and it gives me..                                  Template is missing

Missing template infos/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Sites/2/information/app/views"

Comment: Are you trying to update an existing record or create a new one?

Comment: im trying to create a new one so im not sure why i even need an update action

Comment: To resolve the `Missing template` error, you'll need to issue a redirect out of your Infos#update action. I've updated my answer to reflect this, as well as offer an explanation as to why your `create` action isn't being enacted.

Comment: Thank you a ton, if you are still awake. Its closer but still not exact. I updated the question portion to reflect the new code and to show the new error

Comment: Removing 'get "infos/create"' from you routes should resolve the issue raised in your update.

Comment: same result, just to be sure, I should be submitting the form at http://localhost:3000/infos/create right?

Comment: I sent it to your gmail. tried :3000/infos ad it just kept showing the form over each time i hit submit rather than the flash

Comment: Please do not email private addresses regarding questions on SO. I've updated my answer to address the behavior your are witnessing. See the link attached in update #2 – it cites Rails documentation that states that `create` and `update` actions should be accessed via the HTTP POST method. You are probably trying to submit via HTTP GET.

Comment: got it working, thank you zeantsoi. Sorry for the email. I understand now that it was pointed out that that was uncalled for. As my reputation points imply, i am new to the community and I am not wanting to start off on the wrong foot

Comment: Glad it helped. Since this answer addressed your question, please accept it as correct. It's considered both polite and helpful to do so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work